# Why cases showing runtime error verdict on Hackerrank in python 3

Tags: string, python-3.x, runtime-error

I am a beginner at python. That's why I am trying to solve some basic problems on Hackerrank.But in this problem [String Formatting](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-string-formatting/problem) showing **Runtime error** on my code.
I have tried many different ways to solve this problem but it always shows **runtime error** on my code.

Here is my code:

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(1,n+1):
#Decimal to Octal conversion
    octal=""
    ck=i
    while ck>0:
        a=int(ck%8)
        octal+=str(a)
        ck=int(ck/8)
    octal=octal[::-1]
    #Decimal to Hexadecimal conversion
    hexa=""
    ck=i
    digit={10:'A',11:'B',12:'C',13:'D',14:'E',15:'F'} 
    while ck>0:
       a=int(ck%16)
       if a>=10 and a<=15:
           hexa+=digit[a]
       else:
           hexa+=str(a)
       ck=int(ck/16)
    hexa=hexa[::-1]
    #Decimal to binary conversion
    binary=""
    ck=i
    while ck>0:
        a=int(ck%2)
        binary+=str(a)
        ck=int(ck/2)
    binary=binary[::-1]
    #Formating numbers to print from right align to left
    print(str(i).rjust(n),octal.rjust(n),hexa.rjust(n),binary.rjust(n))
```

**Hackerrank verdict** : Runtime Error!